# Solution to constrained quadratic optimization problem

Tags: convex-optimization

Is there a closed form solution to this constrained quadratic optimization problem?

$$
\mathrm{argmax}_X\ \mathrm{Tr}(AX)\mathrm{Tr}(BX)\\
0\preceq X\preceq I
$$

Where $A$ and $B$ are hermitian positive matrices and $A\preceq I$, $B\preceq I$.

EDIT: The inequalities are with respect to the eigenvalues

Comment: By $\leq$, do you mean element wise inequality or conic inequality with respect to the semidefinite cone?

Comment: Thank you for the question, see edit.

Comment: The notation $\succeq$ is normally used for this kind of conic inequality.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.